# Unexpected identifier error while running conf.js file

Tags: node.js, automation, protractor

Somebody Please let me know what is the mistake in my conf.js file.
I have added my conf.js file and the error displayed.
When i comment the JasmineNodeOpts , the conf.js works without errors. But, i need the default timer.

```
exports.config = {

    directConnect: true,

  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['CreateProject_spec.js'],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome' ,
  }
 jasmineNodeOpts: {
     showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 100000,
  }
};



C:\Users\Sumana\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\example>protractor conf.js
[11:46:29] E/configParser - Error code: 105
[11:46:29] E/configParser - Error message: failed loading configuration file conf.js
[11:46:29] E/configParser - C:\Users\Sumana\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\example\conf.js:19
 jasmineNodeOpts: {
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at ConfigParser.addFileConfig (C:\Users\Sumana\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\configParser.js:135:26)
```

Comment: missing a comma `,` after  `capabilities: {    browserName: 'chrome' , }`. In fact at "line 19" and just before the thing it actually told you. That's how you interpret syntax errors. I would suggest a modern editor (VSCode, Sublime, Webstorm, etc) as they will highlight these with linting before you run the code and get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was missing a comma behind `capabilities`. There are many syntax highlighter such as in Visual Studio code where such errors are detected.

This should fix your error:

```
exports.config = {

  directConnect: true,

framework: 'jasmine',
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
specs: ['CreateProject_spec.js'],
capabilities: {
  browserName: 'chrome' ,
},
jasmineNodeOpts: {
   showColors: true,
  defaultTimeoutInterval: 100000,
}
};
```

Comment: Please don't post answers for "syntax errors". Leave a comment ( if one was not already there ) vote to close or flag and move along.

Comment: Didn't know that, sorry @NeilLunn